# How to discard context reinits during H264 video decoding from GStreamer webrtcbin

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, gstreamer, h.264

Gstreamer pipeline is receiving video this way:

webrtcbin -> rtph264depay -> avdec_h264 -> ...

I've enabled do_nack on rtpbin inside webrtcbin to make video quality better but the problem is that lost buffers from RTP cause 'sometimes' h264 decoder to `Reinit context to ...` which makes the whole output video grey (with only movement visible) until the next keyframe is received (but this can happen many seconds later).

I've noticed that EVENT_GAP is emitted right before context reinit but dropping them doesn't help.

How to make decoding artifacts acting 'as always' on the corrupted video, not to fill the whole video with grey?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution with avdec_h264 but compiling gst-plugins-bad by myself and using openh264dec resolves the problem (suprisingly, it's not available in the repository package on Ubuntu/Debian).